# Ionic / Angular : unable to disable password input auto complete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ionic-framework

I'm designing an app using Ionic Framework / Angular / Cordova and have issues clearing old form values.

When a user logs in, he's routed to another view but when they switch back to the login view (after disconnecting), the login & password fields are still filled with old values.

So I know this question was asked many times here and the main solution is to set input attribute:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

But this has no effect.
I also added

```
document.getElementById('password').value = '';
```

in the login controller with no change.

How can I clear this values?

Comment: Please show us complete `<input>` definition

Comment: <input autocomplete="off" value="" id="password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" required="required">

Answer (score 0):

use autocomplete in js and put this line:

```
 someFormElm.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

EX:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldId" class="firstCSSClass otherCSSClass autocompleteOff" />

JS:

$(document).ready(function(){$("input").attr("autocomplete","off");});
```

Comment: Still no change... I believe that because the browser already has saved the values, now it will always show.. I'm looking for a solution that would clear the value in each case..